# Yii2 select by max date?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

Suppose I have table A with its active record in yii2, What is the best way to can load the record with max created date to the model.

This is the query :

```
     select * 
     from  A 
     where created_date = (
        select max(created_date) from A 
      )
```

Now I am getting the max date first then use it in another access to database ie:

```
    $max = A::find()->select("created_date)")->max();
    $model = A::find()->where("created_date = :date",[":date"=>$max])->one();
```

I am sure that this can be done with one access to database , but I don't know how.

please any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your query is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

You can order your records by `created_date` in descending order and get the first record i.e:

```
$model = A::find()->orderBy('created_date DESC')->limit(1)->one();
```

Why `limit(1)`? As pointed out by [nicolascolman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329313/nicolascolman), according to the [official Yii documentation](https://yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html):

> Neither `yii\db\ActiveRecord::findOne()` nor `yii\db\ActiveQuery::one()` will add LIMIT 1 to the generated SQL statement. If your query may return many rows of data, you should call limit(1) explicitly to improve the performance, e.g., Customer::find()->limit(1)->one().

Comment: Should I use ...->limit(1) also? It's strange but with limit it works faster for me. I have 2 millions rows in my DB

Comment: @Footniko According to the official documentation: Neither yii\db\ActiveRecord::findOne() nor yii\db\ActiveQuery::one() will add LIMIT 1 to the generated SQL statement. If your query may return many rows of data, you should call limit(1) explicitly to improve the performance, e.g., Customer::find()->limit(1)->one(). http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Answer (score 4):

```
$maxdate=A::find()->max('created_date');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$model = A::find()->orderBy("created_date DESC")->one();
```